# how to pass information from one php page to another of a different server?

Tags: php, web

I've a php page, say A, in which I call another page, B which is NOT on the same server, using the header function & passing some parameters in the URL. I wish for some information to be returned to A from B. How do I manage this? The information to be returned may be the contents of a file or a large array.

Say, I use this -

```
    header('location:B.php?getx=23');
```

Now, I need to send some information from B to A. How do I send that information from B? and how do I receive the same at A? The information to be sent from B is sensitive & can't be encoded in the url.

Comment: Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Comment: One option is [cURL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php)

Comment: I've not attempted anything yet. This is where I got stuck with no idea on how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page a.php:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html');// this page will send content to the web browser as html webpage
$json_string = file_get_contents('http://example.com/b.php?param=param&param2=param2');// this is a call to the page b.php with parameters
                                   // now, $json_string -- received from b.php data
$json = json_decode($json_string); // after decoding, $json_string converts to arrays
...                                // there you can do anything else
echo("<html>...");                 // like send page to web browser
```

The page b.php:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json'); // will return json to a.php
                                          // anything you need to prepare the data to send back
....                                      // JSON for php -- array variables
echo(json_encode(Array(...)));            // now we sending the json string to a.php
die;
```

Comment: Please can you explain how this works?

Comment: This solution did exactly what I needed the pages to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can work like this,

Page A send data through url

Page B receives params and process the data.

Page B return Data(Json,Xml or plain html based on your requirement)

Page A can parse this data from the requested url.

Hope it gives some idea..

Answer (score 0):

you can use post method to send data to other server

```
 <?php
     $url='http://localhost/e/admin/test.html'
     $data = array ('foo' => 'bar');
     function mPost($url,$data)
     {

        $data = http_build_query($data);
        $opts = array (
        'http' => array (
        'method' => 'POST',
        'header'=> "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n" .
        "Content-Length: " . strlen($data) . "\r\n",
        'content' => $data
        )
        );
        $context = stream_context_create($opts);
        $html = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
       return $html;
     }
   ?>
```

Comment: Please can you explain how this works?